# Magento - secureNet payment gateway

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am trying integrate secureNet payment gateway on magento.But I Can not find any tutorial. How to integrate secureNet payment gateway on Magento?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To intergrate a payment gateway in magento you need to create a payment module.

Take a look @

- [Create Payment Method Module - Magento Wiki](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/payment/create-payment-method-module)
- [How to create Magento payment module - Inchoo](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/how-to-create-magento-payment-module/)
- [How to create Magento payment module - excellencemagentoblog](http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-create-custom-payment-method)